# Add a custom CSS class to all angular-formio/formio elements

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, bootstrap-4, ionic4, formio

I'm attempting to embed [angular-formio](https://github.com/formio/angular-formio) in an Iconic 4 PWA application. As far as I can tell, formio does not include a template for Ionic. So I have reverted to using [Isolated-Bootstrap](https://github.com/toert/Isolated-Bootstrap) as a workaround. This lets me do the following:

```html
<div class="ion-padding">
  <div class="bootstrap">
    <form-builder [form]="{
      components: []
    }"></form-builder>
  </div>
</div>
```

where I'm wrapping the angular-formio `<form-builder>` element in a div with the `bootstrap` CSS class. This works well and seems to let the Ionic and Bootstrap styles coexist. I will need to apply a few CSS tweaks to get it *just right* but its workable for now.

The issue I have is that formio pops it's own dialogs for editing form elements. These dialogs are inserted into the DOM outside of this element and therefore do not have the required `bootstrap` CSS class.

Is there any way I can tell angular-formio, or the underlying formio.js to add a CSS class to all of its elements and dialogs so that Isolated-Bootstrap will be applied to those elements?

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Comment: No I didn't find a solution for this. I ended up writing my own form builder in Angular/Ionic.

Answer (score 0):

In formio you can use `cssClass` property to apply a bootstrap class to form field And `customClass` to apply your own CSS class.

Comment: But the custom class does not apply to the component when inspecting the element. Why ? Could you please elaborate your answer